# How to use the verb ''provide''

Tags: verbs

Can I use a verb with -ing after the verb provide like:

> This company provide buying this items on the cheap.

I searched it but I couldn't find any answer about this . Although Google Translate translates it to Turkish as I think. I mean after verb takes -ing it becomes noun. Can the noun be used as something?

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of two possibilities.

1) provide *something*

> This institution provides *shelter* for the homeless.

2) provide *one* with *something*

> I hope this answer provides *you* **with** sufficient information to help you understand the usage of provide.

Using +ing right after provide feels unnatural, ungrammatical.
You could rephrase your sentence like this:

> The company provides these items on the cheap [for their customers/employees].

Comment: I just wonder if the verb+ing is noun . Can the noun be used as somethin in a sentence?

Answer (score 0):

*This company provides buying these items on the cheap.* (incorrect)

The answer is no.

You could say, "This company provides the opportunity of buying these items on the cheap."

Note that 'on the cheap' is not a good term to use. It usually refers to goods that may be damaged, counterfeit, or even stolen.

I prefer, "This company provides the opportunity to buy these items at very low prices."